# Explaining induced representation with an example

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm studying induced representation by myself. I've seen there are few different approach to present them and I worked out some example with two of them, but I can't understand this definition in Fulton Harris book at pag. 37: H is a subgroup of G and W is a representation of H, then he defines the induced representation as
$$\text{Ind}W=\mathbb{C}\left[G\right]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}H}W,$$
where $G$ acts as first factor $\rho\left(g\right)\left(e_{g'}\otimes w\right)=e_{gg'}\otimes w$.

I know tensor products, but never seen this notation $\otimes_{\mathbb{C}H}$. Can someone explain to me what this construction is supposed to mean with a plain english explanation and eventually one or two examples?
Thank you in advance

Comment: If $W$ is an $H$-representation, then it is basically a left $\mathbb{C}H$-module via the left $H$-action extended linearly. The algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a $(G,H)$-bimodule, by the left and right multiplication actions, so the induced representation is really just the tensor product of a right $\mathbb{C}[H]$-module with a left $\mathbb{C}[H]$-module. If you're familiar with tensor products of modules, this is really not much different. Since $\mathbb{C}[G]$ carries a left $G$-module structure, the resulting tensor product is a $G$-representation.

Comment: One concrete example with any group such $S_3$ or even $C_3$ would be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: When you say, you know tensor products, I suspect, you mean you know tensor products over $\mathbb{C}$ (or fields in general)? Tensor products can be defined for modules over arbitrary rings, too, and in this case the ring over which the tensor product is constructed is $\mathbb{C} H$ where $\mathbb{C} G$ and $W$ are both $\mathbb{C} H$-modules ($W$ from the left and $\mathbb{C} G$ from the right).

Comment: Your suspect is right, I've never seen tensor product defined such way. Do you have a link, please? Anyway... is there anybody that make a effectively a real example based on this definition of induced representation?

Comment: @Dac0 You're probably best off learning about tensor products over arbitrary rings. The concrete, quick and dirty is that the induced module is essentially the $G$-module consisting of $\mathbb{C}$-linear combinations of simple tensors $g\otimes w$, where $g\in G$ and $w\in W$, with the action that $g'\cdot (g\otimes w)=g'g\otimes w$, and you have the relations $gh\otimes w=g\otimes (h\cdot w)$ (the $\cdot$ being the $H$ action on $W$) for any $h\in H$. Roughly, you can freely pass elements of $\mathbb{C}[H]$ across the $\otimes$ symbol.

Comment: @BenWest your explanation on tensor product was really insightful. Now I think I got what's going on, I think I'll try to answer to my own question if anybody can't produce a plain concrete example.